# VS 2008 - Star Team and multi project solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, version-control, starteam

I have a project which is under source control via Star Team in VS 2008.  I added another project to my solution for an installer, configured it, tested it, etc.  Now, when I go to check in my solution with the new installer, I get the following warning:

> > The project that you are attempting to add to source control may cause other source control users to have difficulty opening this solution or getting newer versions of it.  To avoid this problem, add the project from a location below the binding root of the other source controlled projects in the solution.

There are with options to Continue or Cancel.

My project directory looks like this:

```
/Proj1/
    Proj1.sln
    /Proj1/
        .cs files
        .csproj
        /bin/, etc
    /Proj1_Installer/
        Proj1_Installer.vdproj
        /Debug/
        /Release/
```

Is there something fundamental I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that my debug and resource folders were being put into source control.  Visual studio wants to generate these every time the project runs, so they shouldn't be placed in SC.

Answer (score 1):

The files for the new solution should be in the same location as the projects you already have from source control. For example if you have existing code from source control

```
Source\
  Project1\
     program.cs
  Proejct2\
     program.cs
```

then you need to put your new project in the same folder and project1 and project2

```
Source\
  Project1\
     program.cs
  Proejct2\
     program.cs
  NewProject\
```

"add the project from a location below the binding root of the other source controlled projects in the solution" If you decide to add it to the "MyProjects" folder on your drive, then others won't be able to get it from source control.

I suggest if this is how your physical folder structure actually is, verify the solution file using notepad and check the paths. Maybe it's referencing it using

```
..\..\Path1\Path2
```

instead of

```
.\Path2
```

Comment: And how is this different from the OP's directory structure? Confused.